# Minimum CPU needed for Hazelcast deployment in embedded mode

Tags: hazelcast

What is the minimum CPU needed for Hazelcast Embedded deployment?
As per, Hazelcast IMDG 3.12  Deployment and Operations Guide, it is stated as below.

> "As a rule of thumb, we recommend a minimum of 8 cores per Hazelcast
>   server instance."

The use case we have in our application is primarily for distributed locking purposes.
We are not using any data on Hazelcast Data Grid

However, is the same applicable for embedded mode as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 cores is a minimum that works well in most use cases. If use case is solely about locking and no other feature will be used, 4 cores might be sufficient as well. The mentioned rule is due to the [threading model](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#operation-threading); by default Hazelcast creates operation threads as many as the core count. And those threads are responsible for a number of partitions.

If you are going to use embedded mode, please note that your application will use the same cpu as well, so you need to make sure cpu doesn't become a bottleneck. So I suggest testing based on your needs and see how it goes.